Creating a trailing rolling average without NAs at the beginning of the output
I'm working with a nested dataframe using dplyr. I need to mutate a second nested column with a copy of the data where all numeric columns are replaced with a trailing rolling average of the last 5 rows.
How do I either specify to zoo that I don't want the first five NAs or create a custom function that gives the desired output?
I've tried both rollmean with the partial = TRUE argument and rollapply with a custom function with na.rm = TRUE from the zoo package, but the first 4 rows are turned into NAs, which I don't want.
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

example <- 
  tibble("index" = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)), "data_a" = c(1:3, 1:2, 1:3, 1:2), "data_b" = c(2:4, 2:3, 2:4, 2:3)) %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  nest()

example_ra <- example %>%
  mutate(roll_mean = map(data, ~ mutate(.x, across(
    where(is.numeric),
    ~rollmean(
      .,
      k = 5,
      fill = NA,
      partial = TRUE,
      align = "right"
    )
  ))))



My desired output (as a second list-column named roll_mean) is:



Input B
Input A




1
2


2
3


3
4


1
2


2
3






Output B
Output A




1
2


1.5
2.5


2
3


1.75
2.75


1.8
2.8



I get:



Output B
Output A




NA
NA


NA
NA


NA
NA


NA
NA


1.8
2.8



Thanks :)

"I need to mutate a second nested column ...": please provide your test input.  Currently, your Input A  and Input B appear not to be nested, so your example is not reproducible.

Edited the code to match the example provided.

There are several problems:

rollmean does not have a partial= argument.  Use rollapplyr.  Note r on the end to avoid needing the right= argument.
it seems that nested functions specified by formulas are not supported.  Use function

With these changes
example_ra <- example %>%
  mutate(roll_mean = map(data, ~ mutate(.x, across(
    .cols = where(is.numeric),
    .fns = function(x) rollapplyr(x, width = 5, FUN = mean, partial = TRUE)
  ))))


I guess I missread the documentation on rollmean. Thank you. I'm working with a relatively big df and zoo takes an eternity. Do you know of any alternatives to perform a similar operation faster?

On vectors in the 1,000-10,000 length range rollmean runs one to two orders of magnitude faster than rollapplyr so use rollapplyr for the first 4 elements and rollmeanr for the rest like this: roll <- function(x) c(  rollapplyr(head(x, 4), 5 , mean, partial = TRUE),  rollmeanr(x, 5))
